# Vuetify download previous version 1.5

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

The Vuetify CDN updated to the latest 2.0 version.  How do I access version 1.5 via CDN? Or download the min.js file?  I can't find any links on the Vuetify site to get previous versions.

Thanks,
Donnie

Comment: https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.5.0 or if you want the jsdeliver one look at the [documentation for requesting a specific version](https://www.jsdelivr.com/), or just use: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.0/dist/vuetify.min.css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find 1.5 and other versions of vuetify [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/vuetify)

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you.  2.0 broke some things so I need to downgrade until I can figure out why.  Thanks!

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO but neither is the question itself and both will be closed and deleted shortly making this whole effort pointless.